# Linear functional on Schwartz space non-continuous

Tags: continuity, examples-counterexamples, schwartz-space

I'm looking for a linear functional on the Schwartz space $\mathcal S(\mathbb R^n)$ which is not a tempered distribution. I appreciate any help :)

Comment: Hint:  by Zorn's lemma, a linear functional on a subspace may be extended to a linear functional on the whole space.

Comment: To expend GEdgar proposition : take the normalized gaussian $g$, every function of $S$ can be uniquely written as $f=\lambda g+h$, where $h$ is in the supplementary of $Vect(g)$. Then $L(f) = \lambda$ is linear and not continuous